# JPA @OneToMany mapping inserting null values

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I had a hard time with hibernate OneToMany mapping. I have googled to find the solution from morning nothing helped. Following are my code snippets.

```
package com.student.app.model;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "student_id")
    private long id;
    
    @Column(name = "student_name")
    private String name;
    
    @Column(name = "student_class")
    @JsonProperty("class")
    private String clazz;
    
    @Column(name = "total_marks")
    private int totalMarks;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "student")  
    private List<Subject> subjects; 

    public Student() {
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getClazz() {
        return clazz;
    }

    public void setClazz(String clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public int getTotalMarks() {
        return totalMarks;
    }

    public void setTotalMarks(int totalMarks) {
        this.totalMarks = totalMarks;
    }

    public List<Subject> getSubjects() {
        return subjects;
    }

    public void setSubjects(List<Subject> subjects) {
        this.subjects = subjects;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", clazz=" + clazz + ", totalMarks=" + totalMarks
                + ", subjects=" + subjects + "]";
    }
}
```

**Subject.java**

```
package com.student.app.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "subject")
public class Subject {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "subject_id")
    private long id;
    
    @Column(name = "subject_name")
    private String name;
    
    @Column(name = "marks")
    private String marks;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_id")
    private Student student;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getMarks() {
        return marks;
    }

    public void setMarks(String marks) {
        this.marks = marks;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Subject [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", marks=" + marks + "]";
    }
}
```

**StudentRepository.java**

```
package com.student.app.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.student.app.model.Student;

@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long> {
    Student findStudentByName(String name);
}
```

**POST Mapping**

```
@PostMapping("/students")
public ResponseEntity<?> addStudent(@RequestBody Student student) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Student Object is : " + student);

        Student studentData = studentRepository.save(student);
        if (null == studentData) {
            return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
        }
        URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().path("/{name}")
                .buildAndExpand(studentData.getName()).toUri();

        return new ResponseEntity<>(location, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

**Post Request JSON**

```
{
    "name": "Vinod Kumar",
    "class": "8th class",
    "subjects": [
        {
            "name": "Telugu",
            "marks": 85
        },
        {
            "name": "English",
            "marks": 80
        },
        {
            "name": "Maths",
            "marks": 90
        }
    ],
    "totalMarks": 580
}
```

**Student Table data**

```
STUDENT_ID      STUDENT_CLASS   STUDENT_NAME    TOTAL_MARKS  
1               8th class       Vinod Kumar     580
```

**Subject Table data**

```
SUBJECT_ID      MARKS   SUBJECT_NAME    STUDENT_ID  
2               85      Telugu          null
3               80      English         null
4               90      Maths           null
```

Here the issue is the **STUDENT_ID** column storing **null** values.

Comment: You are storing a Student, (which auto generates an ID), that is fine.   However how are you storing a Subject?  Your JSON has no idea about the student relations... and I am not seeing how you are Creating a Subject, associating (Students) to it, then saving??  The Subject has a mapping to Students, by ID.   How will Subject know which Students to store??

Comment: How can I handle this situation then?

Answer (score 0):

When you save a `Student`, Hibernate smart enough to insert a `Student` record to the database, get that record id and save all subjects of the `Student` with `Subject.STUDENT_ID = generated student id`, *when the student and the subject connected to each other from both sides*.

But by some reasons Hibernate doesn't connect a Subject with a Student as Java objects from the `Subject` side. It doesn't do for you

`subject.setStudent(student)`

This is the reason why `Subject.STUDENT_ID = null` in the database.

Before saving a student you have to assign the student to a subject for each subject, doing it in the loop

```java
emptyStreamIfNull(student.getSubjects()).forEach(subject -> setStudent(student));
```

**Some recommendations**

Your database schema is not convenient. `Student` and `Subject` are tabular data.
So you need an additional object `StudentSubjectMark`.

Also use `Long id` for ids (not `long id`).

You have to log error here

```java
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
}
```